# Is there a way to redefine a Java9 module, by giving export/open privileges only to a particular package in the "destination" module?

Tags: module, java-9, javaagents

`instrumentaton.redefineModule()` gives provision to export/open a particular JPMS Module's package(s) to other module(s). But is there a way to just do the same, but ONLY to a particular package in the destination module (the module to which the package is exported to).

**Right now**

extraExports/extraOpens is a Map with 
key: "Package to be exported in the Source Module " 
value: Set of Modules to export/open to

**What i would have needed** is a Map with

key: "Package to be exported in the Source Module" 
value: Map with Key: "Package in the Destination Module" value: Modules to export/open to

I know that there is no such thing right now, but the underlying question: **Is there a provision to do package level redefinition for Module.**

*A bit more background*: I am writing a java agent, which is not Modular yet. So those gets loaded in to the unnamed-module dumpyard (since i cant use modulepath because of project restrictions ). I want other modules to export/open packages to "just" my agent classes and not to the whole unnamed-module. Writing a custom class loader to load my Agent class and giving the privileges to only the new class loaders unnamed-module, is probably one solution, but then before i Attempt that, want to check if there is another solution.